# Add/Remove SQLite Listview doesn't update

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I've got a listview which grabs info from SQLite Database and displays it. There's an EditText along with an addButton. When addButton is pressed, text in EditText is put into the database, after which the listview is supposed to update. Adding to the database works, however the listview does not update until you pause the activity and resume it again.

In this layout there's also an eraseButton on which all textviews with selected checkboxes shall be deleted from the database and removed from the listview. In this problem, the button does not delete the selected textviews (probably due to some rowid-problems in the database. I believe that it would not update the listview after deletion either as the method is same for addButton.

Any help is appreciated.

**This is the MainActivity**

```
package net.ddns.introzen.jagharaldrig;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


        //SQLite Database
        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


        //listview

        //add items
        /*questions.add("Jag har aldrig");
        questions.add("Jag har aldrig varit");
        questions.add("Jag har aldrig2");

        //Checkboxadapters
        final ListView questionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questionList);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, questions);
        if(questionList != null) {
            questionList.setAdapter(adapter);
            questionList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            questionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        }*/

        final ListView questionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questionList);
        final Cursor cursor = db.getData();
        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[] { DatabaseHandler.COL_QUESTION }, new int[] { R.id.checkedTextView1 },0);
        assert questionList != null;
        questionList.setAdapter(adapter);
        questionList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        questionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        //Erasebutton listener
        final Button eraseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eraseButton);
        assert eraseButton != null;
        eraseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //erasebutton onclick
            public void onClick(View eraseButton) {
                SparseBooleanArray checked = questionList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for(int i = questionList.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if(checked.get(i)) {
                        //What to do with selected listitems
                        db.removeData(i);
                    }
                }
                checked.clear();
                Cursor newCursor = db.getData();
                adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
            }
        });


        //addbutton listener
        final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        assert addButton != null;
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Nextbutton onclick
            public void onClick(View addButton) {
                EditText addText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addText);
                assert addText != null;
                String text = addText.getText().toString();
                db.insertData(text);
                Cursor newCursor = db.getData();
                adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
            }
        });


        //Nextbutton listener
        final Button returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
        assert returnButton != null;
        returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Nextbutton onclick
            public void onClick(View returnButton) {
                Intent mainMenu = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                Main3Activity.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
            }
        });


    }


}
```

**This is the DatabaseHandler**

```
package net.ddns.introzen.jagharaldrig;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "questions.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "questions";
    public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COL_QUESTION = "question";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_QUESTION + " TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    public boolean insertData(String question) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_QUESTION, question);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean removeData(int position) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID+"="+position, null);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_ID+" AS _id, "+COL_QUESTION+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your transaction is commited when you insert into the db?

Comment: Yes, when I close the application and open it again, the added row is present in the listview.

Comment: Hmm, do a querry again, and then say adapter.swap(newCursor)

Comment: Updated MainActivity in original post. Adding to the list aswell as updating to it now works properly.

Deleting from the list WORKS, however only if I add an explicit amount of rows to the listview.

I think there might be an error in the database from previous deleted rows. How to I fill in the empy gaps in the database upon deleting a row?

Answer (score 0):

could you try to add the item to the adapter and then call adapter. notifyDataSetChanged after it.

it look likes this then

```
db.insertData(text)
adapter.add()//the item;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or place the notify method after swapCursor

Comment: Thank you, but the update problem is already solved. See comments above. All that remains now is how to sort the added rows in the database so that when I delete a row, all rows below will be moved up to fill the space of the empty row. Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify the database tables after delete or is it just a display problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding a new cursor after updating the database. Thank you user3431672 for answering.

```
adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
```